# submit page within jquery dialog

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have something like the following

```
$("#Lookup").load(url, function () {
        $(this).dialog({
          modal: true,
          width: 900,
          resizable: false,
          draggable: false,
          position: ['center', 210],
          title: "Lookup",
          create: function (event, ui) {

          }
        });
      });
```

The page that is loaded into the dialog has a search button (it is a lookup page for records) It returns the results to a grid and I select one of them and return it to the parent page, but obviously, clicking the search button posts the whole page back and I end up with the page loaded into the dialog becoming the parent, what I would like is the page within the dialog to postback, within the dialog and not affect the parent page.  Can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `$.get()` instead of `.load()`.

Something like this:

```
$.get({
    url: url,
    success: function (result) {
        //create your dialog and inject the content...
    }
});
```